# What if I give parameter for Date.prototype.getTime()?

Tags: javascript, date, utc, gettime

I create date in two ways:

- new Date('*some date*').getTime();
- new Date().getTime('*some date*');

I did it before I had read on MDN, that `Date.prototype.getTime()` doesn't have parameter. It means second way is wrong. Nevertheless, it gives the same date value the right way gives (`new Date('*some date*').getTime();`) but amount of milliseconds is different and I don't get why.

Could someone explain me?

```js
(function () {

  let dateToCount = "Jan 01, 2022 00:00:00";
  let date1 = new Date(dateToCount).getTime();
  let date2 = new Date().getTime(dateToCount);

  console.log(Date(date1).toString()); // Tue Oct 19 2021 22:41:59 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
  console.log(Date(date2).toString()); // Tue Oct 19 2021 22:41:59 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
  console.log(`date1 = ${date1} ms`); // date1 = 1640988000000 ms
  console.log(`date2 = ${date2} ms`); // date2 = 1634672519002 ms
  console.log(`date1 - date2 = ${+date1 - (+date2)} ms`);  // date1 - date2 = 6315480998 ms

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

> it gives the same date value the right way gives

No, it doesn't - it just that when you were debugging with `console.log(Date(date1).toString());` you fell in yet another trap: missing the `new` operator in the call the `Date`. As [MDN puts it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#return_value):

*Calling the `Date()` function (without the `new` keyword) returns a string representation of the current date and time, exactly as `new Date().toString()` does. Any arguments given in a `Date()` function call (without the `new` keyword) are ignored; regardless of whether it’s called with an invalid date string — or even called with any arbitrary object or other primitive as an argument — it always returns a string representation of the current date and time.*

So if you fix that as well, you'll realise that the two different millisecond values you get back from `getTime()` actually do represent two different dates:

```js
const dateToCount = "Jan 01, 2022 00:00:00";
const date1 = new Date(dateToCount).getTime();
const date2 = new Date().getTime(dateToCount);

console.log(new Date(date1).toString()); // Sat Jan 01 2022 00:00:00, as expected
console.log(new Date(date2).toString()); // Surprise!
console.log(`date1 = ${date1} ms`);
console.log(`date2 = ${date2} ms`);
```